# SQL: How do add a prefix to column names in a JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have sql query like this

```
SELECT * FROM phlegm WHERE JOIN mucus ON phlegm.id = mucus.id JOIN snot ON phlegm.id = snot.id
```

The problem is those tables contain several columns with identical names.

For example all 3 tables contain the column named test

If I retrieve the result of the query in PHP, then I will only get one value named test (`$query->get_result()->fetch_object()->test;`), because the other two get overwritten.

Is there some way to edit that query so that it adds a prefix to all columns from a table? For example, column test from table mucus would be referenced in the query as mucus_test and column test from phlegm would be phlegm_test.

One way would be doing

```
SELECT phlegm.test as phlegm_test, mucus.test as mucus_test FROM phlegm...
```

But I have a LOT of columns and tables and it would make the query longer than the Great Wall of China if I had to name each field one by one.

So is there some way to add the prefix en masse?

Comment: Why not just use shorter alias names like 'SELECT * from phlegm p ON p.id...'?

Comment: `Phlegm` and `Mucus` are not very pleasing table names. Anyway did u tried inner join on all tables

Comment: It is bad practice to use `select *`, the best way would be specifying the columns you need anyway. You can use something like excel to make your life a bit easier.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Used [aliasing](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) to retrieve all values associated from all three tables. if you want to reference only specific column do so by using the `alias_name.column_name` instead of `p.*`, where `*` means all columns belonging to table that the alias is associated with( ie. p refers to phlegm).

```
SELECT p.*, m.*, s.* 
FROM phlegm p 
JOIN mucus m ON p.id = m.id 
JOIN snot s ON p.id = s.id;
```

I removed the `WHERE` from your original query above, not sure why it was there.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, phlegm.test as phlegm_test, mucus.test as mucus_test FROM phlegm...
```